# "error: expected ‘)’ before ‘Project’" in /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h during catkin_make

Tags: ros, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I go into those file and see neither syntax error or the string 'Project'

Do anyone knows what happen?

https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/indigo-devel/clients/roscpp/include/ros/publication.h

```
In file included from /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:32:0,
                 from /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                 from /home/ardrone/catkin_ws/src/droneproject/src/Main.cpp:4:
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h: In member function ‘void ros::Publisher::publish(const boost::shared_ptr<T>&) const’:
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:69:11: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘Project’
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:69:11: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘Project’
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:69:11: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘Project’
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:75:11: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘Project’
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:75:11: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘Project’
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:75:11: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘Project’
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:79:7: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘Project’
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:79:7: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘Project’
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:79:7: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘Project’
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h: In member function ‘void ros::Publisher::publish(const M&) const’:
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:102:11: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘Project’
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:102:11: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘Project’
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:102:11: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘Project’
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:108:11: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘Project’
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:108:11: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘Project’
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:108:11: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘Project’
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:112:7: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘Project’
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:112:7: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘Project’
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:112:7: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘Project’
In file included from /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/parameter_adapter.h:32:0,
                 from /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/subscription_callback_helper.h:35,
                 from /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/subscriber.h:33,
                 from /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:33,
                 from /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                 from /home/ardrone/catkin_ws/src/droneproject/src/Main.cpp:4:
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/message_event.h: In member function ‘typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_void<M2>, boost::shared_ptr<T> >::type ros::MessageEvent<M>::copyMessageIfNecessary() const’:
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/message_event.h:228:5: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘Project’
In file included from /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/subscriber.h:33:0,
                 from /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:33,
                 from /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                 from /home/ardrone/catkin_ws/src/droneproject/src/Main.cpp:4:
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/subscription_callback_helper.h: In member function ‘virtual ros::VoidConstPtr ros::SubscriptionCallbackHelperT<P, Enabled>::deserialize(const ros::SubscriptionCallbackHelperDeserializeParams&)’:
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/subscription_callback_helper.h:160:7: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘Project’
In file included from /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:35:0,
                 from /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                 from /home/ardrone/catkin_ws/src/droneproject/src/Main.cpp:4:
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/service_client.h: In member function ‘bool ros::ServiceClient::call(MReq&, MRes&)’:
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/service_client.h:66:7: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘Project’
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/service_client.h: In member function ‘void ros::ServiceClient::deserializeFailed(const std::exception&)’:
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/service_client.h:180:5: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘Project’
In file included from /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/node_handle.h:40:0,
                 from /opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                 from /home/ardrone/catkin_ws/src/droneproject/src/Main.cpp:4:
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/advertise_service_options.h: In member function ‘void ros::AdvertiseServiceOptions::init(const string&, const boost::function<bool(MReq&, MRes&)>&)’:
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/advertise_service_options.h:62:7: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘Project’
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/advertise_service_options.h:67:7: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘Project’
droneproject/CMakeFiles/DroneProject.dir/build.make:54: recipe for target 'droneproject/CMakeFiles/DroneProject.dir/src/Main.o' failed
make[2]: *** [droneproject/CMakeFiles/DroneProject.dir/src/Main.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:476: recipe for target 'droneproject/CMakeFiles/DroneProject.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [droneproject/CMakeFiles/DroneProject.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:113: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200004/%22error:-expected-%E2%80%98)’-before-‘project’"-in-/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h-during-catkin_make/) by [Alvar](https://answers.ros.org/users/21018/alvar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-12-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is most likely a syntax error in your own code. It would help if you'd add the relevant source code to your OP (`Main.cpp`?).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alvar](https://answers.ros.org/users/21018/alvar/) on 2014-12-24**:
I found out that it is the ROS_INFO, ROS_ASSERT macro causing the error though the reason is ye unknown

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-12-24**:
Again, this is most likely a syntax error in your own code. We can only help you if you show us what you are doing exactly. The `ROS_INFO` and `ROS_ASSERT` macros have been used in hundreds, if not thousands of packages already. I'd be very surprised if they are the cause here.